# Taking image input in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, mnist

I was trying to build a shiny app that predicts handwritten digits using the MNIST dataset. I built the model, but now I am left with taking the image input. I tried using different ways like utilizing canvas in HTML and building my own plot that the user can draw on in R, but those ways were a little bit hard to implement and ended up not working like I wanted. Now I want to take user input as an image, so the user will upload an image file and the model will predict what the handwritten digit in the image is.

I will use the `fileInput()` function. The model I built takes an array of pixels as input (Of size 784 to be exact). My question is how do I take the image file and read it as an array of pixels?

```
fileInput(
  inputId,
  label,
  multiple = FALSE,
  accept = NULL,
  width = NULL,
  buttonLabel = "Browse...",
  placeholder = "No file selected"
)
```

Comment: Do a search with your favorite r-specific term, perhaps “CRAN”, combined with “mnist” ( the classic training and validation image set). Several packages exist to load them so they should have worked examples.

Comment: Actually I did do that, unfortunately there exists only 1 application of this project in shiny. The person that made the project created a custom plot where the user can draw, I contacted him and asked about it, but it was a little bit too advanced for me to understand (The code was also old). Eventually I opted with taking image files as input. @IRTFM